# Why update variable in observable object does not update the view?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, data-binding, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. Learning new properties such as @State, @Binding, @EnvironmentObject etc.

I am currently working on the login template, define a binding @Published variable in observable object which allows to switch between login page and main page. However, when I update the variable inside the observable object, the main page does not show up. It is still in the login page. What is missing in my code?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel



    var body: some View {

        return Group {
            if loginViewModel.signInSuccess {
                MainPageView()
            }
            else {
                LoginView(signInSuccess: $loginViewModel.signInSuccess).environmentObject(LoginViewModel())
            }
        }


    }


}
```

```
final class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject  {
      @Published var signInSuccess:Bool = false;

      func performLogin() {
           signInSuccess = true;
      }

}
```

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    @Binding var signInSuccess: Bool;

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: submit) {
                Text("Login")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)

        }

    }

    func submit() {
        loginViewModel.performLogin()
        // signInSuccess = true;
    }


}
```

If I tried to update binding 'signInSuccess' in the loginView, it can successfully update the view to the mainView. However, is there a way that I can update signInSuccess inside the Observable Object that also update the ContentView to the MainView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just change the view code as the following. 
The binding actually is not necessary.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel 

var body: some View {

    return Group {
        if loginViewModel.signInSuccess {
           MainPageView()()
        }
        else {
            LoginView(signInSuccess: $loginViewModel.signInSuccess).environmentObject(self.loginViewModel)
        }
    }


}


}


   window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView:    ContentView().environmentObject(LoginViewModel())
```

Comment: Thank you for your correct suggestion. I get a better understanding on environmentObject.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an environmental variable, you have to declare it in your SceneDelegate and set it on the ContontentView:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene,
               willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
               options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {


        let contentView = ContentView()
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = HostingViewController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(loginViewModel))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    // etc.
```

Then in your ContenView you don't need to set it in any way on the LoginView as it is held by the enviroment:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    var body: some View {

        return Group {
            if loginViewModel.signInSuccess {
                MainPageView()
            } else {
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your model, make sure you declare your signInSuccess as private(set) so it can only be set from within the class and only read from elsewhere:

```
final class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject  {
      @Published private(set) var signInSuccess:Bool = false;

      func performLogin() {
           signInSuccess = true;
      }

}
```

And finally in the LoginView you just need to include the @EnvironmentObject and everything else will work.

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.loginViewModel.performLogin() }) {
                Text("Login")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }

    }
}
```